# Typescript compiler giving " 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file." in a js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I recently migrated a react js project to a react js with typescript. As you know typescript accepts js files so what I have done is moving all the code to the typescript react app. Also I have added types for every library I needed.

I have this file named HeatLayer.js which is a modified version of react-leaflet-heatmap made by OpenGov.

When I do npm start on the react typescript project I get this error

```
'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.  TS8008

11 | import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
12 | 
13 | export type LngLat = {
   |             ^
14 |   lng: number;
15 |   lat: number;
16 | }
```

When I do **npm start in the react js** app **everything works as expected**.
This is the HeatLayer.js file:

https://github.com/OpenGov/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer/blob/master/src/HeatmapLayer.js

### SOLUTION:

Turns out Heatmalayer.js was made with javascript + flow and typescript compiler is unable to process flow. So **I deleted all types** en used it as a pure javascript file. A better solution would refactor it to be typescript adding typescript syntax and types.

Comment: That file is syntactically correct under both and TypeScript, with _roughly_ equivalent semantics. Since you're using TypeScript, just change the extension to `.ts` and you will be done.

Comment: I have changed the extension  to ts but gives me the error I just posted in the question at the end

Comment: You should be using `radius?: number`

Comment: see last edit, It still doesn’t  work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use types in a javascript file. The error is correct, you should make it a typescript file. Change it to `.ts`. Typescript allows for javascript files, but javascript files do not allow for types. You can covert files one by one if you so choose. Just make sure you compile those files (normally via `tsc`)

---

To your edit you have a few issues:

```
updateHeatmapRadius(radius: number, blur: ?number): void {
```

As the error points to the question mark `?number` isn't a valid type. If you are trying to show an optional you can do that as

```
updateHeatmapRadius(radius: number, blur?: number): void {
```

Now for your next issue you are trying to import a javascript file which doesn't have types. That's going to be one of the most frustrating things converting to typescript. Most popular libraries have type files. You're going to have to create a `.d.ts` file to say that this thing can be anything. Preferably, you'd actually type out the file to get all the goodness of Typescript. Or you can do it as you go. But if you don't have time for that... I normally have a folder called `declarations` then in there you can you can put

`simpleheat.d.ts`

```
declare module 'simpleheat' {
  // typing module default export as `any` will allow you to access its members without compiler warning
  const simpleheat: any;
  export default simpleheat;
}
```

It's actually probably better to declare it as `unknown` - but you can read about the differences. `any` will get you up and running the fastest.

Comment: I have changed the extension  to ts but gives me the error I just posted in the question at the end

Comment: I tried your answer but it doesn't work, could you try to help me, I'm stuck :(

Comment: Edited for you. You may have to do some more reading about typescript and do a few simpler examples before trying convert this file over.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. One more question, how is it possible that when it was a .js file in my react app using javascript for the project it worked and when I moved all the code to the ts react app it was giving me errors?

Comment: It looks like each error I mentioned was due to typescript. Importing a file without a definition, adding a question mark to the wrong spot for an optional, adding a type to a JavaScript file. In general Typescript forces more restrictions and errs where JavaScript will allow a mistake to keep running. In development, I strongly prefer the more strict checks.